# CSS Position Material UI Menu item below its parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I've got a Material UI dialog that contains nothing but some text and an Icon with a Menu options dropdown. The demo can be seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-rain-1rwhf?file=/src/App.js

I'm trying to position the `Menu` component so that it appears just below the `Settings` component when it is clicked. I've specified a `position: relative` on the parent element (i.e. the `Settings` Icon) as well as a `position: absolute` with `top: -10px` to the child element (i.e the `Menu` component), but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I set it up so that when the Settings icon is clicked, the Menu appears directly below the Settings, as well as when the window is resized so that the Menu follows?

**EDIT**:

In case there are any problems with opening the codesandbox, this is what I have.

**App.js**:

```
import "./styles.css";

import { useState } from "react";

import {
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  Divider,
  ListItemText,
  Menu,
  MenuItem
} from "@material-ui/core";
import Settings from "@material-ui/icons/Settings";

export default function App() {
  const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className="blueFont">Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Dialog fullWidth maxWidth="sm" open={true} hideBackdrop={true}>
        <DialogTitle style={{ height: "60px" }}>My title</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>My Content</DialogContent>

        <Divider style={{ width: "100%" }} />
        <DialogActions>
          <div className="settings">
            <Settings onClick={() => setOpenMenu(!openMenu)} />
            <div className="menu">
              <Menu open={openMenu}>
                <MenuItem>
                  <ListItemText>First option</ListItemText>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>
                  <ListItemText>Second option</ListItemText>
                </MenuItem>
              </Menu>
            </div>
          </div>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**styles.css**

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.blueFont {
  color: blue;
}

.settings {
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also refer documentation

https://mui.com/components/menus

I've also created a sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-hooks-0fi6z?file=/src/App.js

```
 const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

<DialogActions>
          <div>
            <Button id="basic-button" onClick={handleClick}>
              Dashboard <Settings />
            </Button>
            <Menu
              id="basic-menu"
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              open={open}
              onClose={handleClose}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "left"
              }}
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: "top",
                horizontal: "left"
              }}
            >
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
          </div>
        </DialogActions>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. How could I make the Popper look like a Menu? The reason I've used Menu is because I'd like for it to resemble one. So for example, a dropdown in the Popper that has "First option" and "second option"?

Comment: That you have to manage using CSS. Check this website out they are using popper for menubar. https://mydukaan.io/highonfashion

Comment: I appreciate the design but that doesn't really give me the technical guidance.

Comment: Okay let me try a example and will share link here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm also looking for how this can be done.

Comment: This is what I tried now with Menu and Menu Items

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-hooks-0fi6z?file=/src/App.js

you can also refer documentation

https://mui.com/components/menus/

Comment: Thank you so much for that! If you'd like to put that as your answer, I'll happily accept.

Comment: I've edited and made changes to original answer. Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to position the `<MenuItems /> to be a bit lower than the "Dashboard"?